# What does time complexity of n log n signify?

Tags: algorithms, big-o

Is it the number of iterations or recursive calls made? Or is it the number of times the conditional check has been applied?

Ex: if there are 10 elements in an array in descending order.
The time complexity will be 10 log 10(base 2).

The answer is 33.2192.

Here is the java implementation of the code.
I have added a count in the while loops where the array is updated.

```
public class MyMergeSort {

    private int[] array;
    private int[] tempMergArr;
    private int length;
    private static int count;

    public static void main(String a[]){
        count = 0;
        int[] inputArrNew = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
        MyMergeSort mms = new MyMergeSort();
        mms.sort(inputArrNew);
        System.out.println("Condition Checks are " + count);
    }

    public void sort(int inputArr[]) {
        this.array = inputArr;
        this.length = inputArr.length;
        this.tempMergArr = new int[length];
        doMergeSort(0, length - 1);
    }

    private void doMergeSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {

        if (lowerIndex < higherIndex) {

            int middle = lowerIndex + (higherIndex - lowerIndex) / 2;

            doMergeSort(lowerIndex, middle);

            doMergeSort(middle + 1, higherIndex);

            mergeParts(lowerIndex, middle, higherIndex);
        }
    }

    private void mergeParts(int lowerIndex, int middle, int higherIndex) {

        for (int i = lowerIndex; i <= higherIndex; i++) {
            tempMergArr[i] = array[i];
        }
        int i = lowerIndex;
        int j = middle + 1;
        int k = lowerIndex;
        while (i <= middle && j <= higherIndex) {
            if (tempMergArr[i] <= tempMergArr[j]) {
                array[k] = tempMergArr[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                array[k] = tempMergArr[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
            count++;
        }
        while (i <= middle) {
            array[k] = tempMergArr[i];
            k++;
            i++;
            count++;
        }

    }

}
```

here is the output:

```
    Condition Checks are 34
```

Is my understanding correct?

Why is the method doMergeSort() not taken into consideration while calculating the time complexity. We know that recursive calls affect performance of the code.

I tried to read the content in below link, but it is slightly difficult to understand at a high level.

For bubble sort it is easy to understand that the for loop runs twice creating a n X n structure resulting into O(n2) complexity.

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis

Comment: but here there are recursive calls also made in the method doMergeSort(). Why is it not taken into consideration when calculating time complexity as we know that recursive calls affect performance.

Comment: No, Big-O complexities don't tell you anything about the actual runtime or the number of steps in an algorithm. They are just a mathematical abstraction to discuss how algorithms scale for large input sizes. That allows us to compare how well different algorithms are suited for large inputs. E.g. we can prove that there must exist some input size after which an O(n) algorithm will always be better than an O(n²) algorithm, but Big-O does not tell us which is better for a specific input size.

Comment: @TusharBanne It is. If it wasn't, you'd end up with an O(n) performance, which is clearly erroneous. I can only urge you to read the question gnat posted and the links therein very carefully.

Comment: @amon As per my understanding, big-O complexities do tell the actual number of iterations required to search, sort or insert elements in a data structure.

Comment: @TusharBanne where/how did you arrive at that understanding? Do you have a link or reference?